# При использованием Popup перестает работать DropDown. Баг Kivy. Python 3

Tags: python-3.x, gui, kivy

Сам код программы рабочий, ошибку не выдает, но после того, как *Popup* запускается больше 2 раз, (кнопка `File->Open или File-Save as` ), все остальные выпадающее меню (`Color mode, Deep Learning`) перестают работать.

Сначала кнопки переставали работать сразу после первой замены картинки, теперь после небольших изменений, работает после 2 двух раз. [Ссылка](https://dpaste.org/cZMU#L) на код.

Comment: Перестают работать потому что скрипт падает с ошибками а закрытие окна не обработано

Comment: home_catalog = os.getcwd()

Comment: Вот для начала дальше сами

Comment: Вы консоль смотрите?